# Linear map of Zonotopes

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polytopes

Consider a linear system with a map $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $y = A x$ with $n \geq m$

The input space $x$ is constrained by a zonotope set $\mathcal{X}
\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ in an $\mathcal{H}$-representation given

$$
\mathcal{X} = \{ \, x \in \mathbb{R}^n\, | \, \,
C_{x}^{T} x \leq d_{x}
\, \}
$$

We need to characterize the output variable $y$ by obtaining a set
$\mathcal{Y} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$
\mathcal{Y} =  \{ \, y \in \mathbb{R}^m \, | \, \,
y = A x ,\, x \in \mathcal{X} \,\}
$$

WE know that the set $\mathcal{Y}$ is also a Zonotope and could be expressed in $\mathcal{H}$-representation as

$$
\mathcal{Y} = \{ \, y \in \mathbb{R}^m\, | \, \,
C_{y}^{T} y \leq d_{y}
\, \}
$$

Our questions are:

1. How to mathematically prove that $\mathcal{Y}$ is a Zonotope.
2. How to compute $\mathcal{Y}$ i.e. obtain $\{C_{y}, d_{y}\}$ given $A$ and $\{C_{x}, d_{x}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathcal{X}$ is the Minkowski sum of line segments $l_1,\ldots,l_k$, then $\mathcal{Y}$ is the Minkowski sum of line segments $Al_1,\ldots, Al_k$ (and hence a zonotope).  As far as computing $C_y$ and $d_y$, this is a well known procedure for any polytope known as Fourier-Motzkin elimination.

Comment: Any details or supporting materials will be appreciated.

Comment: See for example the first part of Theorem 6.1 here
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/polynotes669.pdf

Comment: The material is really helpful but it has been presented for a simple projection on a subset of the input coordinates which is clearly easy using FM elimination. Are there any general approach to do that?